# zend framework controller not found?

Tags: zend-framework, controller

I downloaded the latest version of Zend framework, added a controller and I
can not get it to load.. Here is what I did:

```
C:\zend\Apache2\htdocs>zf create project myproject
Creating project at C:/zend/Apache2/htdocs/myproject
Note: This command created a web project, for more information setting up your V
HOST, please see docs/README

C:\zend\Apache2\htdocs>cd myproject

C:\zend\Apache2\htdocs\myproject>zf create controller mycontroller
Note: The canonical controller name that is used with other providers is "Mycont
roller"; not "mycontroller" as supplied
Creating a controller at C:\zend\Apache2\htdocs\myproject/application/controller
s/MycontrollerController.php
Creating an index action method in controller Mycontroller
Creating a view script for the index action method at C:\zend\Apache2\htdocs\myp
roject/application/views/scripts/mycontroller/index.phtml
Creating a controller test file at C:\zend\Apache2\htdocs\myproject/tests/applic
ation/controllers/MycontrollerControllerTest.php
Updating project profile 'C:\zend\Apache2\htdocs\myproject/.zfproject.xml'

C:\zend\Apache2\htdocs\myproject>
```

Then I tried to hit the controller from the browser..

```
http://localhost/myproject/public/mycontroller/
```

and I get the error: Not Found

The requested URL /myproject/public/mycontroller/ was not found on this server.

I have no idea how to resolve this, and I'm sort of shocked I'm having problems
with the Zend Server.

Comment: It tells you .. "Note: This command created a web project, for more information setting up your VHOST, please see docs/README"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dooh.. Actually the problem was quite simple.. I forgot the mod_rewrite.. Strange Zend didn't turn it on by default.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Zend [Quick Start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.quickstart.html). It looks like you don't have the document root setup properly. Your request should have been http://localhost/myproject/mycontroller or http://myproject/mycontroller - if setup properly.